# What is the diameter of $C_n$ and $P_n$

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I need to find for each $3\le n\in N $ what is $C_n$ Diameter and his Complement graph Diameter
and the same for each $1\le n\in N $ what is $P_n$ Diameter and his Complement graph Diameter.

Here is what i done:
I found out for $C_n$ that its $\lfloor {n\over 2} \rfloor$  and his Complement $\lfloor {n-2\over 2} \rfloor$
I think that $P_n$ is just $n$ but i cant find his Complement Diameter
is that correct? and how can i find the Complement Diameter

Comment: The diameter is the longest [shortest path] in a graph. To show that the diameter is some amount requires you to construct a shortest path with that length, and showing that all other paths are at most as long as that path. For the cycle graph, opposite vertices can be used for constructing the longest [shortest path].

Comment: It looks like you've crammed 5 questions into one sentence.

Comment: @Element118 I know what is a diameter.. but is there anyway to find out in a formal way what are the diameters?
I created $c_3 -C_7$ and noticed that they has same pattern as what i wrote....
but im sure that there is a better way then that am i right?

Comment: As I said, construct a shortest path with the length of the diameter, and show that every shortest path is shorter than or equal to the diameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about C<sub>n</sub> diameter, it is $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. For C<sub>n</sub><sup>c</sup>, it varies, I have'nt found a generalised answer for this, but it is not what you have mentioned. Take example of C<sub>4</sub>, it's complement is not even a connected graph.

For n=3, P<sub>n</sub><sup>c</sup> is not connected.

For n>=4

You probably made a mistake in counting the diameter of P<sub>n</sub>. It is n-1.The complement of P<sub>n</sub> is always 2. (How?)

There are 2 leafs say $u,v$ in P<sub>n</sub>, and rest of the vertices are of degree 2. Now, when we take the complement, the leaves would be connected to every other vertex except to which it was connected earlier say $w$. Now, to check the eccentricity of $u$, it is obvious that its distance to every vertex other than $w$ is 1, but to reach $w$, it needs to go to another vertex ($v$), thus D($u,w$) = 2. Which implies e($u$)=e($v$)=2. Now, lets take a non-leaf $w$, it's distance to every vertex except to which it was adjacent (say $x$ and $y$) in P<sub>n</sub> is 1.  But to reach $x$ or $y$, it needs to go to $v$ and then come to $x$, thus D($w,x$) = 2 = D($w,y$). Therefore, e($w$) = 2.

Thus eccentricity of every vertex in P<sub>n</sub><sup>c</sup> is 2 and hence diamneter of P<sub>n</sub><sup>c</sup> is 2.

Comment: The graph $P_4$ is self-complementary and its complement has diameter $3$, not $2$.

Comment: The complement of $C_n$ has diameter $2$ for $n\ge5$.

Comment: @bof Ahh, I guess I missed out on that one, yes diameter of $P_4$ is 3.... but I guess for $n>4$, the answer is valid....